Computing $2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.
What do we get by quoting $2\mathbb{Z}$ with $6\mathbb{Z}$?
(I want to see if given a commutative ring without unity, can the quotient have unity?)

You can easily write down the representatives and their multiplication table.

Heads up on avoiding downvotes (people can be mean on here), maybe a better way to structure you question: "I'm curious if when given a ring without unity, then will the quotient ring always have unit? An example I'm considering is $2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, but the structure of this ring is confusing me." But to answer your question, your quotient group will have ${[0],[2],[4]}$ as its underlying set. It should be easy to see from here that your ring will not have unit...though if its not, please don't be afraid to ask.

Here's a hint:  $6:2=3$.

@JAG131 The wording is not really relevant in case of a very simple question which should obviously be a duplicate: $2 \mathbb{Z}$/$6 \mathbb{Z} $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$. I did not downvote.

You can just start from $0$ and then add $2$ each time.
Thus, we get three elements: $0+6\mathbb{Z}$, $2+6\mathbb{Z}$, $4+6\mathbb{Z}$ (and $6+6\mathbb{Z}?$) No, since this is equal to $0+6\mathbb{Z}.$
Then check whether it has a unity:
$(2+6\mathbb{Z})(2+6\mathbb{Z})=4+6\mathbb{Z}\neq2+6\mathbb{Z}$, thus $2+6\mathbb{Z}$ can not be a unity.
So, there is only one choice: $4+6\mathbb{Z}$
$(4+6\mathbb{Z})(2+6\mathbb{Z})=2+6\mathbb{Z}$, which is fine. $(4+6\mathbb{Z})(4+6\mathbb{Z})=4+6\mathbb{Z}$, also ok.
Thus, $4+6\mathbb{Z}$ is the unity for this ring.
